# Why I am getting a segmentation fault while inserting elements to the vector of data inside the class?

Tags: c++, c++11, insert, segmentation-fault, stdvector

I am receiving segmentation fault while inserting data inside the vector. I think the vector is not allocated.

I do not want to `reserve` size. How to do it?

```
class A
{
private:
    struct data
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    std::vector<data>Set;

public:
    void insert()
    {
        Set[0].x = 5; Set[0].y = 6;
    }
};

A a;
a.insert(); // Segmentation Fault
```

Comment: use std::vector::push_back. accessing [0] is the problem

Comment: Regarding "I don't want to reserve size" - note this would still be wrong anyway, as `reserve` allocates some memory, but does **not** construct any objects in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think the vector is not allocated.

**Yes**, you are in the right track. You have undefined behaviour due to [accessing un-allocated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Access_out_of_bounds) vector along the lines.

```
 Set[0].x = 5; Set[0].y = 6;
```

You can simply [`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) or [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) the constructed `data` as follows, which does not require acceing the *vector* by subscript operator:

```
void insert()
{
    Set.push_back(data{ 5, 6 });
    // or
    // Set.emplace_back(data{ 5, 6 });
}
```

---

Note: if the `data` contains, non-primitive types, then consider using `std::vector::emplace_back` to construct the `data` *[in-place](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/02/modern-c-features-in-place-construction/)*, rather than default-constructing and assigning the members, as in the given code. There you also need to provide a suitable constructor for the `data` as well.

Comment: Yes , I have mostly non primitive types inside the struct data. Can u show me an example how to do it ?  Like if i write Set.push_back(Data(5,6))  and provide a constructor inside Data . How will it work ? It will create a temporary Data object and push that temporary object in the vector.  So, Will I  be able to retreive this object  later because the temporary object might get deleted?

Comment: @AnirbanSaha My  [first edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57070446/1) was regarding this.  As I mentioned in the *Note*, you need to use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`, which forwards the arguments(parameters of the constructors) directly and construct the `data` object in-place. See the example code given in the cppreference.com: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back#Example

Answer (score 9):

Use 
[`std::vector::push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Accessing the first element ( `Set[0]` ) is undefined behavior.

A default constructed vector is empty.

Comment: Exactly the right answer, but may I suggest a couple of edits? You could make `push_back` a link to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back and format code snippets by surrounding them with backticks.

Comment: @BoBTFish I think that is generally highly accepted to do, even without asking :)

Comment: Sorry. Most I did was eye-sugar but linking to **de**.cppreference is not a good idea. (This might become subject of translation to German.) I spent a vote to compensate... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

By default a vector when created is of size 0, thus trying to access the element Set[0] is wrong and would create a segmentation fault (which here means accessing something which is not present).

Use the std::vector::push_back to avoid the segmentation fault

You could rewrite the function like :

```
void insert()
    {
      data newItem;
      newItem.x = 5; newItem.y = 6
      Set.push_back(newItem)
    }
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Set.push_back`? Also the SEG FAULT is not guaranteed to happen.

Comment: Yes, I meant that . Thanks for pointing it out. Made the edit.